# Rebasing onto a repository with no common ancestor

Tags: git, rebase

I have a lot of code based on an old version of a source repository (created through git-svn). The usptream has since moved to git and now I need to rebase my code onto the new repository.

How do I find a good common point between the repositories (I mean without manually digging through the repositories)?

Answer (score 1):

If you know roughly when the svn -> git conversion happened, you should be able to find at least one commit on `master`/`trunk` which you can correlate.  You might find `git log -S` to be useful here, as it lets you find commits that introduce or remove a given string.

In your subversion-based clone, then, you can find the common parent of your code and the current master.  You can then use the relationship between this parent commit and your correlated one to find the same commit in the new git repository, which should be a suitable candidate for a rebase.

Comment: Yeah this isn't working. The issue is that my code is based of a stable branch with a lot of backported fixes. And the fixes are backported from all over the place :-/

Comment: If you've got a common ancestor, you should be able to pull the content of the stable branch along too.  Then you've at least got everything in one repo and can use standard git tooling to put your changes where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the project was *very* active, you can probably match up your parent commits from svn with the new git repository using the commit timestamps.

Comment: It was very active. Plus I'm starting to think that the branch from the original svn repository was not transferred into the new git repository. So I need to find a good rebase point (that is not too distant from the fork-point).

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment, rather than an answer?

Comment: @Jubobs, it might not have turned out be a very *useful* answer, but it was intended to answer the question.